# Understanding jQuery UI Button Widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

Im looking to recreate the following button after updating to the latest version (button widget was rewritten in 1.12 onwards, However im struggling to get the syntax/classes correct based of the api documentation here: https://api.jqueryui.com/button/

button should look like [image: Image of blue button with text new]

but so far the closest I've got is[image]

the code used to display the above is as follows

```
<button id="btnAddNew" type="button" title="New User Access" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></button>


    $("#btnAddNew").button({
    classes: {
        "ui-button": "ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary"
    },
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-plus"
    },
    label: "New"
});
```

Can anyone point to where im going wrong?

Comment: On a side note you may want to move away from jQuery UI and look for an alternate library as the project itself hasn't been updated in years and appears to be dead or at least dying.

Comment: Yes I agree, I would normally migrate to bootstrap but I don't have that option just need to update the existing code to get it looking as before.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work without issue using Cupertino theme. I suspect that CSS is not loading for your script. I would check to ensure it's not getting 404 error or that no other Styling is conflicting.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnAddNew").button({
    icons: {
      primary: "ui-icon-plus"
    },
    label: "New"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="btnAddNew" type="button" title="New User Access" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></button>
```